# Timelinelite with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I'm trying to have my kinetic tweens be controlled with the timelinelite library.  Is this possible?  I don't want to use the Kinetic controls because they are not ideal, especially when using seek or reverse as they step through the animations.  Which is something I do not want.  I feel I would have much better control using the timelinelite framework.  So, are these two libraries able to integrate with each other?  If so, does anyone have any recommendations for where I should start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can use TimelineLite to drive animation of Kinetic nodes.**

If you put Kinetic commands in TimelineLite's `onUpdate` callback then TimelineLite can control the tweening of Kinetic nodes.

onUpdate is called every time the timeline changes.